# How to Skip Using "use strict" In Node.js 4.0+?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Using `"use strict"` allows support for ES6 features, which Node 4.0 supports, in JavaScript code.

However, it is cumbersome to have this at the beginning of every single back-end code file.

Is there a way to configure Node to just assume `"use strict"` is always in use within an application?

Comment: This will come with ES6 modules.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `"use strict"` does not turn on support for ES2015 features. These features are already built into node. The implementation isn't complete yet (see http://node.green/ for details), but you can certainly use ES2015 features without turning on strict mode.

Comment: To expand my previous comment, for Node 4.x, a lot of the built-in ES2015 support requires you to pass the `--harmony` command line argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `--use_strict` command line option to the `node` command. This will treat all of your code as being in strict mode.

Alternately, you can use the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-strict. That way you don't have to give the command line argument each time.

Comment: This is awesome. The only thing that would be slightly better would be someway to flag this in `package.json`

Comment: I just did a quick Google search and found this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-strict  EDIT: This might not be what you want, as it only handles modules.

Comment: That package looks like it should do the job! Could you update your answer, and I'll mark it as accepted